# How create XElement with specific namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have problem with creating new element in LinqToXml.
This is my code:

```
XNamespace xNam = "name"; 
XNamespace _schemaInstanceNamespace = @"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

XElement orderElement = new XElement(xNam + "Example",
                  new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", _schemaInstanceNamespace));
```

I want to get this:

```
<name:Example xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

But in XML I always get this:

```
<Example xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="name">
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is what you need http://stackoverflow.com/a/4986019/570150

Comment: V4Vendetta: It is similar problem, but now I got this:
`<name:Example xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:name="name"> `

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`<name:Example xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">` is not namespace well-formed as the prefix `name` is not declared. So constructing that with an XML API is not possible. What you can do is construct the following namespace well-formed XML

```xml
<name:Example xmlns:name="http://example.com/name" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
```

with the code

```cs
//<name:Example xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:name="http://example.com/name"></name:Example>

XNamespace name = "http://example.com/name";
XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

XElement example = new XElement(name + "Example",
new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "name", name),
new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi));

Console.WriteLine(example);
```

Comment: I forgot write about this. Namespace name is declared in parent node. After creating xml I always validate this on some xml validator.