# Merge XElement into XDocument and resolve namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, linq-to-xml, xelement

Given the following `XDocument`, initialized into variable `xDoc`:

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition">
  <ReportSection>
    <Width />
    <Page>
  </ReportSections>
</Report>
```

I have a template embedded in an XML file (let's call it `body.xml`):

```
<Body xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition">
  <ReportItems />        
  <Height />
  <Style />
</Body>
```

Which I would like to put as a child of `<ReportSection>`. Problem is if add it through `XElement.Parse(body.xml)`, it keeps the namespace, even though I would think namespace should be removed (no point in duplicating itself - already declared on the parent). If I don't specify namespace, it puts an empty namespace instead, so it becomes `<Body xmlns="">`.

Is there a way to properly merge `XElement` into `XDocument`? I would like to get the following output after `xDoc.Root.Element("ReportSection").AddFirst(XElement)`:

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition">
  <ReportSection>
    <Body>
      <ReportItems />        
      <Height />
      <Style />
    </Body>
    <Width />
    <Page>
  </ReportSections>
</Report>
```

Comment: Check this out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985974/xelement-namespaces-how-to

Comment: @Pheonixblade9: Unfortunately, in my case XML is not created by code, as it is done in dozens of examples on StackOverflow, including the one you mentioned. It is not a problem in creating an XElement from scratch and merging it into the XDocument. It's about XElement.Parse returning a tree of nodes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is happening, but removing the `xmlns` attribute from the body element seems to work:

```
var report = XDocument.Parse(
@"<Report xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition"">
  <ReportSection>
    <Width />
    <Page />
  </ReportSection>
</Report>");

var body = XElement.Parse(
@"<Body xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition"">
  <ReportItems />        
  <Height />
  <Style />
</Body>");

XNamespace ns = report.Root.Name.Namespace;
if (body.GetDefaultNamespace() == ns)
{
   body.Attribute("xmlns").Remove();
}

var node = report.Root.Element(ns + "ReportSection");
node.AddFirst(body);
```

Comment: Very interesting. Indeed, removing `xmlns` attribute manually makes it work. While not having it on `body` in the first place does not work, although both options should have resulted in the same effect. Thanks for digging it up. +1