# Remove xmlns attribute with namespace prefix

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, xelement

This question is a logical continuation of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613917/merge-xelement-into-xdocument-and-resolve-namespaces) - now suppose an `XElement` contains elements in a non-default namespace:

```
<Body xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <ReportItems />        
  <Height />
  <rd:Style />
</Body>
```

I am trying to follow the same approach as suggested in the answer for my previous question, i.e. remove `xmlns` attribute, but it does not work when it's xmlns + prefix, like this `xmlns:xx`.

**TL;DR version**

This works:

```
Dim xml = <Body xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner"/>
xml.Attribute("xmlns").Remove()
```

This doesn't:

```
Dim xml = <Body xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner"/>
xml.Attribute("xmlns:rd").Remove()
```

Getting this error:

```
XmlException was unhandled
The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.
```

How do I remove `xmlns:xx` attribute from an `XElement`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
xml.Attribute(XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/") + "rd").Remove()
```