# How to add a colon inside xml element? Linq to xml C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am generating an XML file from linq query. The xml elements are generated, however I want to add a prefix in each element so it result some thing like the following:-

```
XDocument xDoc =null;

xDoc = new XDocument(
                    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
                    new XElement("EmpLists",
                        new XElement("Employee",
                            new XElement("EmpId", '1'),
                            new XElement("Name", "Sam"),
                            new XElement("Sex", "Male"))));
```

What should I do to have the elements print with their prefix "CP:" as shown below?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CP:EmpLists>
 <CP:Employee>
    <CP:EmpId>1</CP:EmpId>
    <CP:Name>Sam</CP:Name>   
    <CP:Sex>Male</CP:Sex>
   <CP:Address>
      <CP:Street>7A Cox Street</CP:Street>
      <CP:City>Acampo</CP:City>
      <CP:State>CA</CP:State>
      <CP:Zip>95220</CP:Zip>
    </CP:Address>
 </CP:Employee>
 <CP:Employee>
    <CP:EmpId>2</CP:EmpId>
    <CP:Name>Lucy</CP:Name>
    <CP:Sex>Female</CP:Sex>
    <CP:Address>
      <CP:Street>Jess Bay</CP:Street>
      <CP:City>Alta</CP:City>
      <CP:State>CA</CP:State>
      <CP:Zip>95701</CP:Zip>
    </CP:Address>
 </CP:Employee>
 </CP:EmpLists>
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387069.aspx (I'm not a dotnetter, so I'll leave to someone else to construct the actual answer if this doesn't help)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
var url = "YOUR_NS_URL";
var ns = XNamespace.Get(url);

var xDoc =
    new XDocument( 
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
        new XElement(ns + "EmpLists",
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "CP", url),
            new XElement(ns + "Employee",
                new XElement(ns + "EmpId", '1'),
                new XElement(ns + "Name", "Sam"),
                new XElement(ns + "Sex", "Male"))));
```

I get this XML:

```
<CP:EmpLists xmlns:CP="YOUR_NS_URL">
  <CP:Employee>
    <CP:EmpId>1</CP:EmpId>
    <CP:Name>Sam</CP:Name>
    <CP:Sex>Male</CP:Sex>
  </CP:Employee>
</CP:EmpLists>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to utilize a namespace, see the similar namespace [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4986019/1539718). You will need to instantiate an instance, of `XNamespace`, and use it as an `XAttribute`, using `new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "CP", ns)`.

Comment: your example was very helpful and actually the same solution as 'Enigmativity'. Thanks you!