# Exception when using XName and namespace

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

I have an XML file that I must read. I am using `XmlReader` combined with `XElement`. The problem is when I try to use this syntax:

```
var test = field.Element(nameSpace + "value").Value;
```

I get this exception:

> The character ':', hexadecimal value 0x3A, can not be used in a name

The namespace is like `"http://anURL"` so it is correct while the field `XElement` is:

```
<field name="Name" type="String" xmlns="http://anUrl">
    <value type="String"><![CDATA[aName]]></value>
</field>
```

How exactly do I use `XElement.Element()` when I have a namespace involved?

I was referring to answer like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985974/xelement-namespaces-how-to)

Comment: ...yes... my suspicion is that `nameSpace` is a string. Please show the definition.

Comment: @rene it's a string containing the url

Comment: @DanieleSartori If it's a `string` and not an `XNamespace`, that's your problem.

Comment: @rene it works. If you post the answer i'll check as the correct one if you want

Comment: me repeating an answer from the Skeet doesn't make sense. You only needed an extra pair of eyes ;)